# "message": "Property \"Slots\" does not have corresponding setter in class \"Magento\\Quote\\Api\\Data\\CartItemInterface\"."

Tags: magento-2.1, overrides, rest-api

am using Webkul_BookingSystem extension for booking slot in magento2.1.7. 
The issue what I got here: While I add the product details in to cart through Rest API the Slot class showing does not have setter class in CartItemInterface.

webapi.xml file of this extension:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<routes xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../app/code/Magento/Webapi/etc/webapi.xsd">
    <route url="/V1/bookingsystem/slot" method="POST">
        <service class="Webkul\BookingSystem\Api\Data\SlotInterface" method="setStore"/>
        <resources>
            <resource ref="Webkul_BookingSystem::setStore"/>
        </resources>
    </route>
</routes>
```

**Api/Data/SlotInterface.php**

```
 <?php
    /**
     * Webkul Software.
     *
     * @category  Webkul
     * @package   Webkul_BookingSystem
     * @author    Webkul
     * @copyright Copyright (c) 2010-2017 Webkul Software Private Limited (https://webkul.com)
     * @license   https://store.webkul.com/license.html
     */
    namespace Webkul\BookingSystem\Api\Data;

    interface SlotInterface
    {
        /**
         * Constants for keys of data array. Identical to the name of the getter in snake case.
         */
        const ENTITY_ID = 'id';
        /**#@-*/

        /**
         * Get ID.
         *
         * @return int|null
         */
        public function getId();

        /**
         * Set ID.
         *
         * @param int $id
         *
         * @return \Webkul\BookingSystem\Api\Data\SlotInterface
         */
        public function setId($id);
    }
```

Url pass in postman: http://mysite/V1/bookingsystem/slot
Method: POST.

```
data in form:
{
"cart_item": {
"quote_id": "11",
"sku": "newbookingproduct",
"qty": 1,
"Slots": {
"2":
{
"booking_from" : "26 November, 2017, 01:06 AM",
"booking_to" : "26 November, 2017, 01:11 AM"
}
}
}
}
```

**Error message:**

```
    {
"message": "Property \"Slots\" does not have corresponding setter in
class \"Magento\\Quote\\Api\\Data\\CartItemInterface\".",
"trace": "#0
D:\\xampp\\htdocs\\dashboard\\api\\vendor\\magento\\framework\\Reflection\\NameFinder.php(59):
Magento\\Framework\\Reflection\\NameFinder->findAccessorMethodName(Object(Zend\\Code\\Reflection\\ClassReflection),
'Slots', 'getSlots', 'isSlots')\n#1
D:\\xampp\\htdocs\\dashboard\\api\\vendor\\magento\\framework\\Webapi\\ServiceInputProcessor.php(158):
Magento\\Framework\\Reflection\\NameFinder->getGetterMethodName(Object(Zend\\Code\\Reflection\\ClassReflection),
'Slots')\n#2
D:\\xampp\\htdocs\\dashboard\\api\\vendor\\magento\\framework\\Webapi\\ServiceInputProcessor.php(322):
Magento\\Framework\\Webapi\\ServiceInputProcessor->_createFromArray('Magento\\\\Quote\\\\A...',
Array)\n#3
D:\\xampp\\htdocs\\dashboard\\api\\vendor\\magento\\framework\\Webapi\\ServiceInputProcessor.php(119):
Magento\\Framework\\Webapi\\ServiceInputProcessor->convertValue(Array,
'Magento\\\\Quote\\\\A...')\n#4
D:\\xampp\\htdocs\\dashboard\\api\\vendor\\magento\\module-webapi\\Controller\\Rest\\InputParamsResolver.php(101):
Magento\\Framework\\Webapi\\ServiceInputProcessor->process('Magento\\\\Quote\\\\A...',
'save', Array)\n#5
D:\\xampp\\htdocs\\dashboard\\api\\vendor\\magento\\module-webapi\\Controller\\Rest.php(299):
Magento\\Webapi\\Controller\\Rest\\InputParamsResolver->resolve()\n#6
D:\\xampp\\htdocs\\dashboard\\api\\vendor\\magento\\module-webapi\\Controller\\Rest.php(216):
Magento\\Webapi\\Controller\\Rest->processApiRequest()\n#7
D:\\xampp\\htdocs\\dashboard\\api\\var\\generation\\Magento\\Webapi\\Controller\\Rest\\Interceptor.php(24):
Magento\\Webapi\\Controller\\Rest->dispatch(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))\n#8
D:\\xampp\\htdocs\\dashboard\\api\\vendor\\magento\\framework\\App\\Http.php(135):
Magento\\Webapi\\Controller\\Rest\\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))\n#9
D:\\xampp\\htdocs\\dashboard\\api\\vendor\\magento\\framework\\App\\Bootstrap.php(258):
Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http->launch()\n#10
D:\\xampp\\htdocs\\dashboard\\api\\index.php(39):
Magento\\Framework\\App\\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http))\n#11
{main}"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get around this by using extension attributes. The magento docs describe how this can be done for the product interface / repository.

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/extension_attributes/adding-attributes.html

However this is obviously something that the extension provider should resolve.